# DynamoDb provisioned capacity, high batch get volume

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How should one calculate the read unit capacity for DynamoDb? Here is the use case:

API that needs to retrieve 1000 - 10,000 records per request. No relational processing, simply key based. <1000 requests are expected per day, however, latency is important. So DynamoDb configuration needs to retrieve 10,000 records in < 1 second.

Each record has 5 string attributes, with keys of length 6 and values of length 8 (ex `{'pk_123': 'abcdefgh', ...}`)

Naively, my guess is 1k min, 10k max read unit capacity w/ autoscaling on and target utilization at 70%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple calculation would be the following

`10000rps / 4kb / 2(eventually consistent) = 1250`

So if you're consistent throughput is 10k RPS then 1250 RCU is what you'll consume.

Setting a min will depend on how often you ramp down and how sharp its required to ramp up. If you have steady traffic always above 1k, then a good base would be 1k. However, if you have long periods of no traffic, it could be wasteful.

One thing I always ask people to do is to use on-demand for a short period, and then you can make much better decisions knowing your access patterns and throughput consumption.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you intend to have a single instance of your API making 1,000-10,000 calls or not. So I'll point out that being able to make 10,000 requests in a second is going to be require at minimum 10 instances of your API making those requests.

DDB provides "single-digit millisecond performance", which does not include network or client latency.

If some of those reads are repeated, DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) may be of help.  As DAX provides "microseconds for millions of requests per second for read-heavy workloads"

Comment: Every API call will retrieve between 1k and 10k rows. The specific array of IDs will change depending on the request

Comment: @jbuddy_13 seems a bit off to me, any commonality between the entries such that you could use Query over a GSI to retrieve multiple rows at once?

Comment: And if a GSI and Query really aren't an option, check out [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) .   A `WHERE PK IN (...)` gets broken into multiple GetItems() for you.